# jQuery ajax get request to php not retrieving any data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display the full name of the selected city from the dropdown in the paragraph. But the jQuery ajax call is giving no output.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Learn Javascript</title>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="states">
<option> LDH </option>
<option> JLD </option>
<option> CHD </option>
</select>
<br/>
<p>The Full name is: <span id="fullname"></span></p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#states').change(function() { 
    selectedState = $('#states option:selected').text();
    $.get('learn.php?state='+selectedState, function(data) {
        $('#fullname').html(data);      
    });
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**learn.php**

```
<?php 

 switch ($_GET['state']) {
     case 'LDH' : 
     echo 'Ludhiana';
     break;
     case 'JLD' :
     echo 'Jalandhar';
     break;
     case 'CHD' :
     echo 'Chandigarh';
     break;  
 }
?>
```

> When the dropdown state is changed, this is supposed to print the full name of the selected city by retrieving data from the php file.

Comment: the error is here: `$_GET [$state]` should be `$_GET['state']`

Comment: @k102 i was checking to see if it echoes, actually there is `$_GET['state']` & not working.

Comment: did you try `selectedState = $(this).val();`? and try `alert(selectedState );` you'll get to know, wthr any data being passed or not.

Comment: @ManjunathHegde i don't think it will alert anything, as selectedstate is only initialized after the dropdown item changes. Or correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: @BaljeetSingh, ok, so can you look in firebug (or whatever) console - what exactly is sent to the server and what is the answer?

Comment: @BaljeetSingh: i don't know what you understood, i meant put an `alert` after declaring the `variable`, not in `ready function`, here it is-> `var selectedState = $(this).val();` `alert(selectedState );` put them in `change function`

Comment: in detail>
`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#states').change(function() { 
    var selectedState = $(this).val();
    alert(selectedState);
    var url='learn.php?state='+selectedState;
    alert(url);
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('#fullname').html(data);      
    });
        });
});
</script>`

Comment: @K102 actually nothing on the console

Comment: @ManjunathHegde GET http://localhost/learn/learn.php?state=JLD 404 (Not Found)  [with your code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your spaces inside the option tag.
you can get results by using one method from given below 2 methods 
**Method 1:**

```
<select id="states">
<option value="LDH"> LDH </option>
<option value="JLD"> JLD </option>
<option value="CHD"> CHD </option>
</select>
```

and in jquery change From

```
selectedState = $('#states option:selected').text();
```

to

```
selectedState = $('#states option:selected').val();
```

**Method 2**

use the trim() method in your PHP file

```
switch (trim($_GET['state']))
```

teste  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YUWB2/222/) is

Answer (score 1):

Could you alert formatted url or log to console on `$.get() .fail()`

```
$('#states').change(function() { 
    selectedState = $(this).val();
    url = 'learn.php?state=' + selectedState;
    alert(url);
    $.get(url, function(data) {

        $('#fullname').text(data);      
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: ok, is your script src path correct? type  $  enter in your console is it a function.. or 'undefined' ?

Answer (score 1):

You have space in your text ie in option text.

So alway use value attribute.

Change your code to

```
    <select id="states">
        <option>LDH</option>
        <option>JLD</option>
        <option>CHD</option>
    </select>
```